# mingw32-g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, codeblocks, mingw32

I just installed Code::Blocks 12.11 and create a console application by the Wizard the hello world  code was in there by default. I tried to compile it but I come across this build error:

```
-------------- Build: Release in example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -O2     -c "E:\Workspace\C++\Code Blocks\example\main.cpp" -o obj\Release\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Try looking on to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476526/wxwidgets-2-9-4-include-and-lib-gcc-lib-mswu-no-such-file-or-directory-error-on/17481601#17481601   and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457862/wxwidget-2-8-12-not-working-in-codeblocks/17468133#17468133........I think you have not specified the environment variables path

Comment: Similar question (with answer) here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377964/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-codeblocks