# Making WxWidgets work in C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I installed precompiled WxWidget libraries and tried to run the default program in CodeBlocks but it gives the following error:

```
    mingw32-g++.exe: error: bin\Release\new2.exe: No such file or directory
```

Paths for WxWidget Libraries and MinGW are already specified.
My question is; How to make CodeBlocks generate a .exe file for WxWidgets project?

I have already tried all solutions listed in this question: ["No such file or directory" error in CodeBlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377964/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-codeblocks#17634058)

Complete Build Log:

```
-------------- Build: Release in new2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -Wno-unused-
local-typedefs -Wall -O2 -ID:\WxWidgets\wxWidgets2.8\include -I\msw -c 
C:\Users\ShifaShah\Documents\new2\new2App.cpp -o obj\Release\new2App.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -Wno-unused-
local-typedefs -Wall -O2 -ID:\WxWidgets\wxWidgets2.8\include -I\msw -c 
C:\Users\ShifaShah\Documents\new2\new2Main.cpp -o obj\Release\new2Main.o
windres.exe -ID:\WxWidgets\wxWidgets2.8\include -I\msw  -J rc -O coff -i 
C:\Users\SHIFAS~1\DOCUME~1\new2\resource.rc -o obj\Release\resource.res
mingw32-g++.exe -L -o bin\Release\new2.exe obj\Release\new2App.o 
obj\Release\new2Main.o  obj\Release\resource.res -s -mthreads  -lwxmsw_core -lwxbase -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -
ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -mwindows
mingw32-g++.exe: error: bin\Release\new2.exe: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Comment: Press build button first.

Comment: Building the project is what results in above mentioned error.

Comment: Please post complete build log then.

Comment: I have posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -L -o bin\Release\new2.exe
```

Here's the problem. The `-L` flag requires an argument, but the usual argument (a directory to search for libraries) is not provided. So the next flag, `-o`, is interpreted as an argument to `-L`, and `bin\Release\new2.exe` is interpreted as a name of an input file, which of course doesn't exist yet.

Check your compiler flags and make sure there's no stray `-L` anywhere, and no "additional libraries directory" is specified as a white space string or similar.

Comment: Check compiler flags from build options, right? There is no -L flag there.

Comment: @13.SS CodeBlocks is getting this erroneous flag from somewhere. I have mentioned another possibility, an empty search directory in linker settings, check it out. An undefined environment variable there will result in an empty directory.

Comment: Following Link Libraries are defined in Linker Settings:
wxmsw_core, wxbase, wxpng, wxzlib

No undefined environment variable.

Comment: @13.SS Not libraries. Search directories.

Comment: I have got a compiler in there; \msw. And nothing specified in Linker sub-tab.

Comment: @13.SS How should the linker find your wxwidgets libraries then? There's no magic trick to pull their location out of thin air. You need to specify the folder in the linker tab [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/File:05_search_directories.png).

Comment: Thanks it worked! I got loads of errors now but this problem's solved.