# wxWidget 2.8.12 not working in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm learning to use wxWidget 2.8.12 with Codeblocks 12.11. I have followed the instructions on this site to install wxWidgets and Codeblocks:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef

When I try to create the project and run the demo app I get the error:

```
fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
```

The following picture will show this better:

[image]

I have followed the instructions, but still I get the error...what seems to be the problem? :(

Thnx for any help

P.S.

Here is an overview what I have done:

1) I downloaded Codeblocks including MinGW (codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe)
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#windows and I have installed them using the .exe file

2) I have edited my User PATH environment variable to according to the reference page I have used

3) I have downloaded wxWidgets installer from this link and installed it:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/2.8.12/wxMSW-2.8.12-Setup.exe/download?use_mirror=garr

4) I have entered the directory `C:\<wxWidgets root>\build\msw` and inputted the following command in command prompt:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
```

After letting wxWidgets build and trying to run my demo app I get the error I mentioned in Codeblocks :(

**NOTICE FUTURE READERS: Install wxWidgets to a directory without whitespace in the path name! Otherwise this will cause trouble**

Comment: Check in \lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx.  Is that directory in your includes?

Comment: @stark I have that directory yes. I'm not quite sure what you mean by include? :) Do you mean it like as in C++ #include "myclass.h"? Or do you mean like compiler search path or something, sorry if my questions are dumb, I'm a newbie x)

Comment: P.S. How can change the file search paths in CodeBlocks? My main problems just seem to be that certain header files are not located...

Comment: Look under project build options->search directories tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the Below Link which i have put.It will be very useful.I have also installed wxWidget 2.8.12 with Codeblocks 12.11 using This Link.

[Setting up wxWidgets(2.9.4) with Code::Blocks(12.11) in Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuPiZ86EFhQ&feature=em-share_video_user)

Type These below steps in **Command Prompt** after you finish installing the wxWidgets2.8.12 and CODEBLOCKS 12.11.

`gcc -v`

`mingw32-make -v`

`cd /D C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw`

`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean`

`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1`

`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1`

- If the problem still persists after doing all the above steps then You're missing an important compiler search path in your build options.
- Make sure you choose the correct wxWidgets build configuration when running the wxWidgets project wizard.
- If re-running the wizard isn't an option, then open your project's build options and add "$(#wx.lib)\gcc_dll\mswu" (assuming a monolithic Unicode DLL build) to the compiler search paths.

Comment: +1 @vasanth kumar thank you for your help :) P.S. I will try the link and let u know if it worked :)

Comment: P.S. That did it! :) Thnx a lot dude ;D

Comment: Damn...now when I tried to do the exactly same steps on another win 7 machine, I failed :S This time I got different error though. CodeBlocks was complaining about \include and \lib\gcc_lib\mswu no such file or directory... What do I need to do to modify my search path? Is this what I need to do now? So do I go to Project --> Build Options --> then what? Where do I add the $(#wx.lib)\gcc_dll\mswu? What does $(#wx.lib) stand for here? Is it a global variable I should set or something?

Comment: @jjepsuomi I think you haven't given the wxWidgets Location in the wxWidgets Project.Check it out in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476526/wxwidgets-2-9-4-include-and-lib-gcc-lib-mswu-no-such-file-or-directory-error-on/17481601#17481601" I have Given the Solution there.Try it out

Comment: +1 @vasanth kumar thank you vasanth :) I'll give it a try, you're a king ;D

Comment: @jjepsuomi I appreciate that :)StackOverflow is best and It will always clear every doubt and questions in Programming :)

Comment: +1 @vasanth kumar I agree :) I will try again all the things you've guided me to do and reply on what happens :)