# wxWidgets-2.9.4\include and \lib\gcc_lib\mswu No such file or directory error on CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm trying to learn C++ programming with wxWidgets and CodeBlocks (with MinGW) and earlier today I succeeded in installing the software (after some trouble) to my Windows 7 computer with the guidance given to me in this post:

[wxWidget 2.8.12 not working in Codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457862/wxwidget-2-8-12-not-working-in-codeblocks)

Later on the same day, I did the exact same steps on another Windows 7 machine and after creating a wxWidgets project and trying to compile and run it I got the following errors:

```
\wxWidgets-2.9.4\include: No such file or directory
\wxWidgets-2.9.4\lib\gcc_lib\mswu: No such file or directory
```

I have checked and these folders really do exist on those locations...so what seems to be the problem here again?...on the earlier post user asanth kumar guided me that if the steps given in the guide don't get the job done, then I'm missing an important compiler search path in my build options.

Ok, so what do I do? Where do I enter the search path? What is the search path, etc. I'm very new with wxWidgets and CodeBlocks so I don't know very much terminology. If anyone should know what to do, could you please give me like step by step instruction what to do e.g. like Click Project --> Build options --> ... and so on

I have used the latest CodeBlocks (12.11) and wxWidgets (2.9.4) installers

Thank you for any help :)

UPDATE:

here is the build log: (I'm using CodeBlocks 12.11 and wxWidgets 2.9.4)

```
   -------------- Build: Debug in TEST (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

windres.exe -I"C:\Users\Jonne\Omat ohjelmat\wxWidgets-2.9.4\include" -I"C:\Users\Jonne\Omat ohjelmat\wxWidgets-2.9.4\lib\gcc_lib\mswu"  -J rc -O coff -i C:\Users\Jonne\DOCUME~1\CODEBL~1\TEST\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\resource.res
gcc: error: ohjelmat\wxWidgets-2.9.4\include: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ohjelmat\wxWidgets-2.9.4\lib\gcc_lib\mswu: No such file or directory
windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Here is also a picture where you can see Build options, global variables and build log on my CodeBlocks:

[image]

**NOTICE FUTURE READERS: Install wxWidgets to a directory without whitespace in the path name. The problems in this post was because the directory path had spaces in it**

Comment: can you add the build log to your question? That shows what commands C::B is using to build your project.

Comment: @greatwolf sorry I cannot add them today any more, but I will add them tomorrow.

Comment: When I say add, I meant edit your question to include that info in there. I don't think SO has a limit on editing your own questions.

Comment: @greatwolf I have added the build log :)

Comment: The log looks incomplete. There's more to the command if you scroll up.

Comment: @greatwolf sorry about that, I will update it ASAP

Comment: btw, if the log is really long, you can put it on pastebin.com and refer a link back to it in your question.

Comment: @greatwolf okay, thank you :) Fortunately it wasn't too long, I included the rest.

Comment: I suspect the space in the path may be the problem. Try moving wxwidgets to its own directory without any spaces. Remember to update the C::B search path and settings to reflect the new location.

Comment: @greatwolf Thank you for the assistance, I will do that right away and let you know :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi hey you have installed wxWidgets2.9.4 in "C:\Users\....." ..Thats should not be installed there(wrong path)....Try installing it Like "C:\wxwidgets2.9.4"...It will work after that..Now uninstall wxWidgets2.9.4 and reinstall it with the path i mentioned now.Also do the Steps which i had mentioned in my Solution after that.

Comment: @greatwolf That one did it! Thank you! I installed wxWidgets to a directory without spaces and voila :)

Comment: glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a wxWidgets project.Have you did this?

`File->New->Project->wxWidgets Project->Click Go->Click on Next->click on the suitable wxWidgets 2...version->click Next->Give project Name->Click on Next->Click on Next`

After that the Following below Screen comes in the Wizard. Give the wxWidgets Location(Path where You installed the wxWidgets 2.9.4)

[image: Specifying the Location of wxWidgets in CodeBlocks in wxWidgets Project]

[image: Compiler configuration]

[image: library Settings]

[image: Mode of application]

After that click on Finish.

- **For Environment Variable Path Setting**
- Follow the Below Steps:

  `Right click on MyComputer->Click on Advanced Systems settings->click on Environment Variables->click on New->Give variable name=Path and variable value="C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" -> click ok`

[image: Environment Settings]

`

- Try The Following Steps.It will work.

---

**Updates about Build settings**:

[image: COMPILER]
[image: RESOURCE COMPILER]
[image: LINKER]

Comment: hi vasanth, darmet...I did the same steps, but still the error persists...funny because on another Windows 7 computer I have no problem...I will try checking my steps, I followed the video and the steps you gave in this post. I have added Build log to my post if it helps.

Comment: @jjepsuomi hey you have installed wxWidgets2.9.4 in "C:\Users\....." ..Thats should not be installed there(wrong path)....Try installing it Like "C:\wxwidgets2.9.4"...It will work after that..Now uninstall wxWidgets2.9.4 and reinstall it with the path i mentioned now.Also do the Steps which i had mentioned in my Solution after that

Comment: @jjepsuomi check my Solution. I have updated Build options Settings.See the screenshot.The paths of resource compiler,compiler and linker should be like that.

Comment: +1 It worked! =) I installed wxWidgets in another directory without any spaces in the path "C:\wxwidgets2.9.4". Thank you!! Now the problem is completely solved! :)

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem as this and I somehow solved my problem.
I transfer my wxWidget folder to another location path that don't have white space name on it's path. For example above, "C:\Users\Jonne***Omat ohjelmat***\wxWidgets-2.9.4\include"
the path has white space between Omat ohjelmat. Try transfering it where the path contains no white spaces. For me, I put it on C:\wxWidgets-3.1.2

Comment: There is a big bold sentence at the end of the question mentioning this.